# Getting error when using a button to access a route in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Whenever I try to tap  the button created in the code below when I load the app,the debug console gives me this error.

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/1000hz_route", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Here's the code I am attempting to run. How would I go about fixing this error?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:audiotest/UI/player_widget.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:audiotest/UI/homepage1.dart';


const flutaud1 =
    'https://audio.jukehost.co.uk/694139d474ee606401cc3aa8160159ac14662cd8/093232dd0c4';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
        title: "TestAudio",
        initialRoute: '/audio_selection',
        routes: {
          '/audio_selection': (context) => AudioSelection(),
          '/1000hz_route': (context) => MainPersistentTabBar1(),

        }));

class AudioSelection extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  IntroScreenstate2 createState() => IntroScreenstate2();
}

class IntroScreenstate2 extends State<AudioSelection> {



  Widget _tab(List<Widget> children) {
    return Center(
        child: new Container(
      child: new SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: children
              .map((w) => Container(child: w, padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0)))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }



  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
      child: _tab([
        Text(
          'Audio 1000 HZ',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        PlayerWidget(url: flutaud1),
        new MaterialButton(
          child: new Text('Select 1000 hz'),
          onPressed: () {

            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/1000hz_route');
          },
        ),

    ])
    )
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but the way I am telling you will get your project up and running. Let me know if it works for you.

Do this inside your `onPressed`

```
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
 builder: (context) => MainPersistentTabBar1())
);
```

Instead of

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/1000hz_route');
```

Comment: Great @Kingsod. Happy to help